# Javascript Exercise - Reverse 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Reverse the values of a 2 dimensional array that could extend `n` times.

```
[1, [2, [3, ... [n, null]]]]
```

Given:

1. All arrays always have a length of 2
2. Last array in the list will contain an index 1 of null

Example:

- `[1, [2, [3, null]]]` will output `[3, [2, [1, null]]]`
- `[1, [2, [3, [4, null]]]]` would output `[4, [3, [2, [1, null]]]]`

I'm not sure if I'm describing it right but I came across this exercise today and came up with a fairly obvious solution.

```
var ars = [1, [2, [3, null]]], rev = null;

function r(x) {
    rev = (rev == null) ? [x[0]] : [x[0], rev];
    if( x[1] !== null )
        r(x[1]);
}
r(ars);
console.log( rev );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5b4xntwg/

I am by no means a javascript expert, so I was wondering if there was a better way to do it?

Comment: Does the array always end in a `null`?  Also, your example seems to leave that out of the final result.

Comment: I'm not sure that "2D" and "reverse" are quite the right terms here. This is a nested array and you are, for want of a better term, turning it inside out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RocketHazmat- The bottom array should always end with `null`. Something that I missed, apparently.

Comment: @MattBurland - Yeah, I suppose you're right. Turning it inside out is more appropriate. But like I said, I really just came across this exercise today and don't really know how to describe it. (it was shown to me by a co-worker).

Comment: @MattBurland: Well, it is an array containing arrays (and an int).  So, I guess it's not quite a 2D array.

Comment: Your implementation isn't quite correct and produces the result `[3, [2, [1]]]` (no `null`). If you change the first line of the function to just `rev = [x[0], rev];`, then it will work correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a more concise approach that doesn't have side-effects:

```
function r(arr, acc) {
    acc = acc || null;
    return arr ? r(arr[1], [arr[0], acc]) : acc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5b4xntwg/1/

It goes through the following recursive calls for the input `[1, [2, [3, null]]]`:

```
r([1, [2, [3, null]]]                     )
r([2, [3, null]]     , [1, null]          )
r([3, null]          , [2, [1, null]]     )
r(null               , [3, [2, [1, null]]])
```

On the last call, `arr` is `null` (this is the base case), so it just returns `acc`, which has the value `[3, [2, [1, null]]]`.

One thing worth mentioning is that this nested array structure is basically a [cons list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons), which is used extensively in functional programming and is very conducive to recursive operations.

Lastly, here's an iterative version:

```
function r(arr) {
    var acc = null;
    while (arr) { 
        acc = [arr[0], acc]; 
        arr = arr[1]; 
    }
    return acc;
}
```